# Select * from table where ID list is on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
use temp1
select * from [TZraw].[dbo].[A1]
where [TZraw].[dbo].[A1].[ID] in [select F1 from info1]
```

I am trying to select all the records from TZraw table A1 that match every record in temp1 table F1

Comment: Is F1 the id ? All you have to do is return the ID from info1. `select * from [TZraw].[dbo].[A1] where [TZraw].[dbo].[A1].[ID] in (select F1 as id from info1)`

Comment: Have you checked the syntax for a join statement?

Answer (score 4):

Use parenthesis:

```
select * from [TZraw].[dbo].[A1]
where [TZraw].[dbo].[A1].[ID] in (select F1 from info1)
```

Instead of square brackets on the subselect.

Answer (score 3):

Try round brackets for the subquery:

```
use temp1
select * from [TZraw].[dbo].[A1]
where [TZraw].[dbo].[A1].[ID] in (select F1 from info1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need parenthesis for the `IN` clause

```
select * from [TZraw].[dbo].[A1] 
    where [TZraw].[dbo].[A1].[ID] 
    in (select F1 from info1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your query

```
... in (select F1 from info1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect - the subquery should be in parens - `()`, not square braces `[]`.

Use a join instead of a subquery - SQL is better optimized for it:

```
SELECT first.* 
FROM [TZraw].[dbo].[A1] AS first
  INNER JOIN info1 AS second
    ON first.ID = second.F1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a temporary table

Select *
From Tzrav ti
Where .... ti...<>t...

REATE TEMPORARY TABLE SalesSummary (
Select*
From Temp1 t
Where ....
)